# Pandas' cut does not work as expected

Tags: pandas

I do the following cut on a data frame:

```
df['Age_Groups'] = pd.cut(df.Age, [0, 60, 120, 240, 360, 480, 600, 720, 940], 
                                labels=['0-5', '5-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '> 60'])
```

Does this mean that values 0 to 60 are included in '0-5'? Is 60 excluded, or is zero excluded in 0-5, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must accord your bins  to the labels :

```
df['Age_Groups'] = pd.cut(df.Age, [0,6,10], labels=['0-5', '6-10'],right=False)

"""                                
    Age Age_Groups
0     0        0-5
1     1        0-5
2     2        0-5
3     3        0-5
4     4        0-5
5     5        0-5
6     6       6-10
7     7       6-10
8     8       6-10
9     9       6-10
10   10        NaN
"""
```

[From the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), left bounds are by default excluded, right included :

> right : bool, optional
>   Indicates whether the bins include the rightmost edge or not. If right == True (the default), then the bins [1,2,3,4] indicate (1,2], (2,3], (3,4].

Here (`right = False`) 0,6 is on the contrary `[,6)`.